# 2013 Honda Civic LX, No start after driving through standing water

Tags: honda, troubleshooting, civic

Hi my husband drove our 2013 Honda Civic LX 4Dr sedan (1.8liter engine) through some standing water(he was forced to because all entrances to our apartment complex were flooded) during a rainstorm the other night. The next day it wouldn't start, no click & no crank but the radio, heat and lights work( and aren't dim). I know we should take it to a mechanic and that is what we will do but we are hoping to try some things at home to get it started so we don't have to get it towed. Any thoughts or advise would be so appreciated. 
warning lights when the key is turned: Low oil pressure indicator, Charging system indicator, EPS, and the Malfunction indicator lamp blinks.
Battery seems ok

Comment: The lights can work fine even with a badly-discharged or defective battery, so this doesn't prove the battery is good. The lack of click suggests that when the car was immersed, something in the starter system (the starter solenoid? other wiring or a relay?) got thoroughly wet, is maybe still just full of water, and isn't now capable of operating correctly. . You might try jump-starting the car from another vehicle. If it starts, you can drive it to the mechanic for a more complete exam. If it doesn't start, you'll need a mechanic to come to the car to work on it, or a tow.

Comment: It may have water in the piston cylinders, stop trying to start it as engine damage will result, take it to a mechanic.